Forcing OpenVPN process to run with a specific group using nmcli
I am struggling with this script of mine that should prepare a secure VPN connection with VPN kill switch and I need some help.
What I am trying to do (in general):
My goal is to set up a very strict firewall, with iptables (nftables are acceptable too), that accept traffic only through VPN and drop everything else (lo and tun is ok). Then, using nmcli, to establish VPN (in my case OpenVPN) connection.
I really like the idea of making firewall rules based on owner group (-m owner --gid-owner openvpn) (based on this answer OpenVPN kill switch on Linux) that OpenVPN process is running with, because it doesn't care to what IP the VPN is connected to. And I want to be using Network Manager (nmcli) for taking care of establishing VPN connections because it makes clear indication in the taskbar that connection is established.
Where I got stuck:
I don't know how to force nmcli to start openvpn with openvpn group as an owner.
What I have done:
I have changed ownership of whole /etc/openvpn directory to openvpn:openvpn.
I am setting my iptables rules something like this:
iptables -F
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
...
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix 'My iptables log (nm-openvpn)...: ' -m owner --gid-owner nm-openvpn
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix 'My iptables log (openvpn)...: ' -m owner --gid-owner openvpn
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix 'My iptables log (root)...: ' -m owner --gid-owner root
...
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m owner --gid-owner openvpn
...
# ACCEPTing lo, tun+ and ESTABLISHED connections

And then making connection with:
nmcli con import type openvpn file $vpn_config_file
nmcli con mod $conf_filename vpn.user-name $vpn_auth_username
nmcli con mod $conf_filename +vpn.data "password-flags=0"
nmcli con mod $conf_filename vpn.secrets "password=$vpn_auth_password"
nmcli con up id $conf_filename

Looking at openvpn process with ps command looks something like this:
root      791155  0.0  0.4  14936  9856 ?        S    04:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 5060 udp --explicit-exit-notify --remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 4569 udp --explicit-exit-notify --remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 80 udp --explicit-exit-notify --remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 1194 udp --explicit-exit-notify --remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 51820 udp --explicit-exit-notify --remote-random --connect-timeout 20 --nobind --dev tun --cipher AES-256-GCM --auth-nocache --tls-crypt /root/.cert/nm-openvpn/CON_NAME-tls-crypt.pem --remote-cert-tls server --reneg-sec 0 --verb 1 --syslog nm-openvpn --tun-mtu 1500 --mssfix 0 --script-security 2 --up /usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --debug 0 791150 --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_172 --tun -- --up-restart --persist-key --persist-tun --management /var/run/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-UUID unix --management-client-user root --management-client-group root --management-query-passwords --auth-retry interact --route-noexec --ifconfig-noexec --client --auth-user-pass --ca /root/.cert/CON_NAME-ca.pem --user nm-openvpn --group nm-openvpn

and like this:
USER       UID     PID    PPID    PGID   GID     SID COMMAND
root         0     644       1     644     0     644 NetworkManager
root         0  791150       1  791150     0     644 nm-openvpn-serv
root         0  791155  791150  791150     0     644 openvpn

Looking at logs I see:
...
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali sudo[791098]:     kali : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/kali/scripts ; USER=root ; COMMAND=./make-secure-connecton_01.sh --vpn --vpn-config ../OpenVPN-configs/CON_NAME.ovpn --vpn-auth ../OpenVPN-configs/auth.txt
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali sudo[791098]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by kali(uid=1000)
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali NetworkManager[644]: <info>  [1720858341.2867] agent-manager: agent[8ca661d4854db87f,:1.1299/nmcli-connect/0]: agent registered
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali NetworkManager[644]: <info>  [1720858341.2894] vpn[0x55b900d791e0,UUID,"CON_NAME"]: starting openvpn
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali NetworkManager[644]: <info>  [1720858341.2898] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="UUID" name="CON_NAME" pid=791144 uid=0 result="success"
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: OpenVPN 2.6.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO]
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: library versions: OpenSSL 3.2.2-dev , LZO 2.10
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: DCO version: N/A
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:51820
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali kernel: My iptables log (root)...: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=33759 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56563 DPT=51820 LEN=62 UID=0 GID=0 
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:51820
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 13 04:12:21 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: write UDPv4 []: Operation not permitted (fd=6,code=1)
Jul 13 04:12:24 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: write UDPv4 []: Operation not permitted (fd=6,code=1)
Jul 13 04:12:24 kali kernel: My iptables log (root)...: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34099 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56563 DPT=51820 LEN=62 UID=0 GID=0 
Jul 13 04:12:28 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: write UDPv4 []: Operation not permitted (fd=6,code=1)
Jul 13 04:12:28 kali kernel: My iptables log (root)...: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35001 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56563 DPT=51820 LEN=62 UID=0 GID=0 
Jul 13 04:12:36 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: write UDPv4 []: Operation not permitted (fd=6,code=1)
Jul 13 04:12:36 kali kernel: My iptables log (root)...: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35994 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56563 DPT=51820 LEN=62 UID=0 GID=0 
Jul 13 04:12:41 kali nm-openvpn[791155]: Server poll timeout, restarting
...

...and the result is that firewall doesn't allow openvpn process out.
My observations:

Even though I add user and group lines for openvpn user/group in OpenVPN config file they are ignored.
Even though Network Manager adds "--user nm-openvpn --group nm-openvpn" when starting OpenVPN the OpenVPN process runs as root. (NOTE: I would like that nmcli adds "--user openvpn --group openvpn")
And as a consequence firewall sees all traffic as originating from the root. And, as a prof, when adding "iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m owner --gid-owner root" rule than VPN works.

My question (based on what I assume where the problem originates from):
How can I force openvpn service to run as openvpn group using only nmcli command?
NOTE:
I would really appreciate a solution that doesn't involve modifying OpenVPN configuration file directly, but rather enforcing changes through nmcli command options (modifying connection configuration).
Any help or a hint in the right direction will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

"How can I force openvpn service to run as openvpn group using only nmcli command?" - While the context is security, I don't think that this specific issue here is an information security problem -> off-topic here. Try [unix.se] instead.

NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay It already told you that it's not because of NetworkManager, but the "user change" / "privilege drop" doesn't occur right at the beginning because there are stuff that needs to be done with root first. So apparently that this "nice idea" you got turns out to be untested / incomplete / utopian.

Yes, I saw that, but because I am not very familiar with inner workings of openvpn command I didn't really know what "delayed" meant in this context. So I just took it as an error about failing to downgrade privileges, what was obvious to me even without this log entry, and that was it. I didn't find any clue in this line why downgrade is failing and why openvpn still needs root privileges. Can you provide some information for what openvpn still needs root privileges and what can I do to help openvpn downgrade privileges?

And just as a small note, though you pointed out one of the main problems, there openvpn tries to downgrade to nm-openvpn, but I would rather convince him (through nmcli) to downgrade to my openvpn group.
